# How does one set up a Linode with a certain number of inodes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, inode

Normally when one creates a Linode, they choose a plan, and then deploy a Linux distribution, and choose how much of the disk to allocate. Normally there is a swap partition and a main partition.

But once you do that, the filesystem is already created with a certain number of inodes! So how do you set up a Linode (Ubuntu 12.04 KTS) with a certain number of inodes?

I don't know a lot about linux file systems.

Comment: Is there an option with Linode to format the partition by yourself?

Comment: I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Did you manage to do this in the end?

Comment: No. Haven't found time to figure it out. But I imagine you would just have to deploy linux on it yourself without using any of the automated deployments that linode has. If you figure it out let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an option to partition the drive yourself, you can decide the number of inodes on the partition.

Here is how:

You can do some math and use the option `-i` with your `mkfs.*` command to decide the number of inodes created.

```
 -i bytes-per-inode
              Specify  the  bytes/inode  ratio.   mke2fs  creates an inode for every bytes-per-inode bytes of space on the
              disk.  The larger the bytes-per-inode ratio, the  fewer  inodes  will  be  created.   This  value  generally
              shouldn't be smaller than the blocksize of the filesystem, since in that case more inodes would be made than
              can ever be used.  Be warned that it is not possible to expand the number of inodes on a filesystem after it
              is created, so be careful deciding the correct value for this parameter.
```

For the convenience of calculation lets say the size of your drive is 10,000,000 bytes, now if you use:

`mkfs.ext4 -i 1000 /dev/yourdrive`

It will format the drive and create 1 inode per 1000 bytes, ie, on your 10,000,000 bytes drive it will create 10,000 inodes. By default, the `bytes-per-inode ratio` is 16384 as defined in `/etc/mke2fs.conf`

If you don't have an option to partition the drive yourself, then I am sorry there is no way you can change the number of inodes.

Comment: I imagine that one can always repartition a drive (reduce size, or create new partitions) - I just don't have enough linux experience to know how right away! XD